# How to upload file from request to google drive using django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, google-drive-api

I made a web with django, where when I upload a file with a form, the file will be uploaded to google drive.

The question is how do I get the file that I got from `request.FILE['file']` to upload to google drive?

this my code

```
user = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
tfile = request.FILES['file']
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=Credentials(user))

media_metadata = {
  'name': tfile,
  'parents': [folder.objects.filter(user__username=user)[0].id_folder]
}

media = MediaFileUpload(tfile, mimetype='image/jpeg')

upfile = drive.files().create(body=media_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

After you got your file from the request you just give it all the properties you want to give it and upload it like in the following code:

```
gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents'[{'id':'1pzschX3uMbxU0lB5WZ6IlEEeAUE8MZ-t'}]})
# Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.
```

if you need any help there is a site that explains every single step about
[upload google drive file](https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/upload-files-to-google-drive-using-python)

Comment: I'm not use `pydrive` but with `googleapiclient`

Comment: so try following the [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#python)